# How can I see a Dynamics365 table?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, powerapps

I created a PowerApp by connecting to Dynamics365 and choosing the 'Currencies" table. In the tutorial video I watched, the narrator was able to see his app's table in Dynamics365 and was able to add and edit the records in that table, which would then show up on the PowerApp and vice versa.

When I bring up Dynamics365, I only see my PowerApps, I do not see a "Currencies" table. How can I see the Currencies table in Dynamics365? I have an Office365 Developer tenancy.

I am using a canvas app.

I attached images of my PowerApp, my Dynamics365 page, and the screenshot of the video I was watching that shows the presentor's Dynamics365 page which looks very different from mine and has the table with the data in it. He is using the Sales Leads table which I was not able to find in my list of Dynamics365 tables, that's why I used the Currencies table.

[My power apps edit screen][1]   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTNYe.png

[My Dynamics365 home page ][1]  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEtxi.png

[Dynamics365 table from video][1]  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvtKn.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that video tutorial - see the browser address bar, it says `https://xxxxx.crm.dynamics.com` which is Dynamics 365 CRM, you can go there by clicking the `Dynamics 365 - custom` tile in your `https://home.dynamics.com`

You are connecting to that Dynamics 365 instance in your canvas app as one of the Datasource connector. I can find it like below.

[image]

One more thing, that video shows classic UI whereas you may land in UCI (Model driven PowerApp UI). [Read this tip](https://exptechsolutions.blogspot.com/2019/04/d365-ce-quick-hacks-switch-to-classic.html) to avoid surprises & confusions.

Comment: When I clicked on the Custom tile, I landed in  UCI. I then changed that URL to...https://<your orgname>/main.aspx?forceclassic=1  and that brought up the site that was on the video. But , I don't see how I can access the Currencies table from that site

Comment: @Burak Go to Settings - Business Management - Currencies. If this answer helped you, upvote/mark it as answer to help others

Comment: I only see Queues, Connection Roles, and Relationship Roles under Settings -> Business Management

Comment: @Burak probably Marketing/Sales modules were not picked when you spun this CRM organization. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/admin/try-dynamics-365-online

Answer (score 0):

can you provide some more details on what type of app you're building (Canvas or Model) and where you don't see the currencies table? Would be great if you could send a screenshot of where you're expecting to see it but don't.

I did a really quick test in my environment, and was able to create a canvas app connected to the currencies entity :

[image]

Comment: I am using a Canvas app. I added the screenshots to my first question above.

Comment: In the screenshot from the video, they are using a model driven app - this is something you need to create, you wont just be able to access currencies there automatically. You can read more about creating a model driven app here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/model-driven-apps/build-first-model-driven-app

Answer (score 0):

This Url you can use in Dynamics 365 F&O:

```
Environment =SysTableBrowser&prt=initial&limitednav=true&TableName=Name_Table
```